# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]: Reading a file via jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, file-not-found

i started using Jupyter and fell into a problem. Whilst trying to read a file called 'vgsales' it gave an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File vgsales.csv does not exist: 'vgsales.csv'
```

I have put the 'vgsales' folder which has my csv file within it in my desktop with the Jupyter notebook.
Not sure where i went wrong, Please help!
Thanks

Code used:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('vgsales.csv')
df
```

Comment: if you file named also vgsales.csv try that `df = pd.read_csv('vgsales/vgsales.csv')`. If not - change vgsales.csv to the name of your file

Comment: You are reading the file from the local folder, run `ls` in a notebook cell to see if the file exists. Share the results of `ls` in your question so we can help you.

Comment: @Oysiyl i tried that but gave the same error

Comment: @MohamedAliJAMAOUI This is the result: Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is C473-C313

 Directory of C:\Users\PC

28/06/2020  11:40    <DIR>          .
28/06/2020  11:40    <DIR>          ..
21/06/2020  11:43    <DIR>          .atom
12/06/2020  13:20    <DIR>          .config
12/06/2020  13:20    <DIR>          .eclipse
14/10/2018  16:39    <DIR>          .idlerc
28/06/2020  11:40    <DIR>          .ipynb_checkpoints
27/06/2020  11:01    <DIR>          .ipython
27/06/2020  17:12    <DIR>          .jupyter

Comment: 12/06/2020  13:21    <DIR>          .p2
24/11/2019  13:47    <DIR>          .PyCharmCE2019.2
12/06/2020  13:20    <DIR>          .tooling
14/06/2020  11:54    <DIR>          3D Objects
27/06/2020  10:45    <DIR>          anaconda3
27/06/2020  17:08    <DIR>          Anaconda3 (64-bit)
17/10/2018  16:48    <DIR>          Apple
14/06/2020  11:54    <DIR>          Contacts
13/02/2020  11:42    <DIR>          Creative Cloud Files27/06/2020  10:45    <DIR>          Documents
27/06/2020  17:41    <DIR>          Downloads
12/06/2020  13:05    <DIR>          eclipse

Comment: 12/06/2020  13:20    <DIR>          eclipse-workspace
14/06/2020  11:54    <DIR>          Favorites
14/06/2020  11:54    <DIR>          Links
27/06/2020  17:46            16,605 machinelearn.ipynb
14/06/2020  11:54    <DIR>          Music
23/03/2019  00:43    <DIR>          OneDrive
18/06/2020  13:06    <DIR>          Pictures
26/06/2020  18:30    <DIR>          PycharmProjects
14/06/2020  11:54    <DIR>          Saved Games
14/06/2020  11:54    <DIR>          Searches28/06/2020  11:40            18,871 Untitled.ipynb

Comment: 14/06/2020  11:54    <DIR>          Videos
               3 File(s)         35,548 bytes
              32 Dir(s)  15,407,120,384 bytes free

Comment: @iqram the file isn't in the local folder. I suggest that you start reading about how python interacts with "file" and how to identify the right file path: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/

Comment: @MohamedAliJAMAOUI How would i put the file in the local folder?

Comment: copy it to the same folder of the jupyter notebook.

Comment: The jupyter notebook is in my desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Though the notebook is on your desktop, you still can find out which folder it is in by simply right click on it and choose  `property`. Then you can copy your csv file to the same folder
- To list which files are in local folder when you are inside a notebook, use `!ls`, note that you need `!` for the command to work

Comment: Thank you! It worked but the '!ls' command didn't work and gave the message:                   
 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ooh I forgot, ls is a UNIX command so it does not work on Windows, you need to use dir instead